# How to change the Microsoft schema version

Tags: wpf, xml-namespaces

Until now the xlmns:x seemed not important for me but now I like to create a ResourceDictionary with an array of type "x:String".
The default xlmns:x Namespace references to version 2006, but does not support string. Since 2009 it is [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee792002(v=vs.110).aspx). So I like to use a newer version.
Which steps are necessary for get it done?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMBFipsReminderUI">
    <x:Array x:Key="DataGrid_SampleItemSource" Type="x:String">

    </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The renaming did not help, because visual studio can't find the namespace. 1. Is there an option for adding this namespace?

2. How can I change the default version? So that the new namespace will be used when I create a new Resource, Page etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is a type in the `System` namespace of the `mscorlib` assembly:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMBFipsReminderUI"
                            xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <x:Array x:Key="DataGrid_SampleItemSource" Type="{x:Type s:String}">
        <s:String>a</s:String>
        <s:String>b</s:String>
        <s:String>c</s:String>
    </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```